# SFMC GroupConnect Setup: how to do it?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to use the GroupConnect feature on SFMC, but when I try to create a new message there's no account to select in the dropdrown list.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Should some sort of integration be done first? If so, how? I can't really find anything on the web about this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't and information about requirements to set up is missing from documentation. At this point the only advise you can get it to ask your account executive (we are already most of the way down this path). They will get in touch with Salesforce Professional Services who will be able to perform the configuration for you at a cost. Cost will depend on your specific requirements.